# Is there a @Query in spring Data Redis?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, amazon-elasticache

I have been reading about spring Data Redis which is quite similar to spring data JPA.
I have a USER class that has key has user id and value as the User object. I am trying to find all the user id's (key) from the "/user" hash where this data is stored.

Spring data had this cool feature of using @Query which is apparently not working with spring data redis.

```
@Query("Select c.key from User c")
Set<String> getAllUserKey();
```

I have tried the above code but it is giving me error that unrecognized property Key. I have gone through the documentation and google and don't think so this can be done using spring-data redis.

Just wanted to confirm my understanding and also would like to know what is the best way to approach this use case. I want to gather statistics around how many keys are stored under a hash and other things which would have been very easy to do with @Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in Spring Data Redis, the searching capability is limited to searching over secondary indices (created/maintained in Redis SETs). Spring Data Redis provides "Automatic implementation of Repository interfaces including support for custom query methods." So you can do simple repository-powered repo search methods like `findByXXXandYYY.`

To get full-search capabilities, Redis introduces RediSearch (https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/quick_start/), a search engine packaged with Redis Stack (https://redis.io/docs/stack/) that enables searching over HASHes and JSON documents stored in Redis.

To use Redis Stack features from Spring, there is Redis OM Spring (https://github.com/redis/redis-om-spring). A library that extends Spring Data Redis with Redis Stack functionality. It's still early in its development but getting close to a 1.0 release (disclaimer: I'm the main contributor to the library).

With OM you can create search indices for a collection (Hash/JSON) and user repositories methods to do more complex searching, or use the `EntityStream` class to search with a Java-streams-like API.

Comment: I tried using redis om instead of spring data redis directly but initially I could not get my application started, after resolving multiple issues I got my application running but when I do any repository call it gives me an error - failed to connect to JEDIS. DNS unknown which was working fine now uth spring data redis . I am using spring 3.0 , redis om 0.0.8 and creating a custom jedisconnectionfactory bean

Comment: @Joey come to https://discord.gg/redis and I can assist you with your app issues. Cheer. BSB

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use redisTemplate and redisTemplate.keys("*")

Comment: This would return all the keys. I do not want to see the key I want to get the count of key-values stored under a hash